# My speaker makes a buzzing sound only when the aux cable is NOT connected

Tags: audio, loudspeakers

I seem to have the opposite of the common problem of buzzing when AUX is connected in that the speaker is fine if the aux is connected to a device, but if I remove it then it starts to buzz.

Quick background on the issue, I used to use the aux input on one of the speakers (this is a stereo setup, they are PA style speakers) to input from my keyboard as well as be connected to a mixer via a DIN cable.

I feel like I have done something, I know you are supposed to turn the speakers off before connnecting/disconnecting but I have accidentally done that a few times, and I think this problem has come from that.

Basically my question is what is the problem here? And is there a way I can fix it?

edit: the other speaker in the setup works fine, it is only this one which I had used with the keyboard

edit2: I am using the second input for now, and have turned the volume down on the first input section as that is the source of the buzzing, but I would still love to get this fixed if possible

Comment: This is all a bit confused. Bear in mind we cannot see over your shoulder. Which AUX, on what equipment [names, model numbers etc] & DIN isn't exactly a pro format… do you mean SpeakOn, or XLR.. or what? Or do you mean MIDI, which is actually DIN? Pictures might help too. Also, did you try replacement cables, alternative power sources, confirmed earthed sockets? The more info you give, the better the answers will be.

Comment: It's an electro voice zlx12p, I'm not too hot on the terminology sorry.

As for the AUX it's just a simple 3.5mm jack input, as for the DIN cable it doesn't matter it will buzz whether it's in or not unless as described the AUX cable is connected to another source.

Comment: And replacement cables won't do anything as it's not the cables that are the issue rather the lack of cables in this instance, when I don't have an AUX cable plugged into the 3.5mm jack then it buzzes but if I plug it in then the buzzing stops.


I'm really sorry I'm not sure how to describe it any simpler, it's two 3-pin DIN inputs with the first having an AUX input as well. The first DIN input and the AUX are controlled by the same knob and the second is separate, by turning the first knob down it stops the buzzing but of course it means I can only use the second input.

Comment: To add, the sockets are fine and it never had this issue before plus the second speaker has no problems at all. Earthing is fine too, the issue only started after I was using the AUX input to play my keyboard through this one.

Comment: Are you saying that when you have nothing, except the power cable, plugged in it buzzes, or when the aux is plugged into the speaker and the other end is connected to nothing?

Comment: Yes, Timinycricket, that's exactly what happens. But then when it is connected to something the buzzing stops. I don't know if something may have broken in the aux input circuitry but I've never known this problem happen before.